# how to modify the style of a row of a table with formattable/ kableextra

Tags: r, dplyr, knitr, kableextra, formattable

I have bar table like that ([what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB4ey.png)).
My problem is that I would like the last row to be without color-bar (like by default:with only the number )

[image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6zmv.png)

```
data(mtcars)

library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(formattable)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

mtcars[1:5, 1:4] %>%
  mutate(
    car = row.names(.),
    mpg = color_bar("lightgreen")(mpg),
    cyl = color_bar("lightgreen")(cyl),
    disp = color_bar("lightgreen")(disp),
    hp = color_bar("lightgreen")(hp)
  ) %>%
  select(car, everything()) %>%
  kable("html", escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling("hover", full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(5, width = "3cm")
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call `color_bar("lightgreen")` gives a function that formats a vector with the bar in the background.  So if you want to format only the first part, write your own function that only formats the first `n-1` entries that way.  For example:

```
my_color_bar <- function(color) {
  mainpart <- color_bar(color)
  function(x) {
    start <- x[-length(x)]
    last <- x[length(x)]          
    c(mainpart(start), last)
  }
}
```

Then produce the table using that function instead of the original one:

```
mtcars[1:5, 1:4] %>%
        mutate(
                car = row.names(.),
                mpg = my_color_bar("lightgreen")(mpg),
                cyl = my_color_bar("lightgreen")(cyl),
                disp = my_color_bar("lightgreen")(disp),
                hp = my_color_bar("lightgreen")(hp)
        ) %>%
        select(car, everything()) %>%
        kable("html", escape = FALSE) %>%
        kable_styling("hover", full_width = FALSE) %>%
        column_spec(5, width = "3cm")
```